# Why does pages allocation with order of 10 or 11 using __get_free_pages() usually fail?

Tags: linux, memory, kernel

My system memory is plenty (a server with 24GB). In my system, the kernel space is allocated with 320MB and 120MB for crash kernel. The rest of the memory is used for other purposes. However, when I use `__get_free_pages()` to allocate contiguous pages with order of 11, and the kernel fails to allocate 2^10 pages. Why?

According to [makelinux](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-8-sect-3)

> The maximum allowed value for order is 10 or 11 (corresponding to 1024
>   or 2048 pages), depending on the architecture. The chances of an
>   order-10 allocation succeeding on anything other than a freshly booted
>   system with a lot of memory are small, however.

Why is that so? Each page in my system is 4KB (4096 bytes), 2^10 pages = 1024 pages, and the total size is 1024*4096 = 4 194 304 (bytes) ~ 4MB. It's only 4MB of contiguous space and the kernel is very small: vmlinuz is only 2.1MB and initrd is 15MB. The total memory consumption of the whole kernel is ~300MB. It must be more than enough for the kernel to allocate 4MB of contiguous pages. Even in normal machine with 1GB/3GB kernel/user, and sure the kernel won't use up the whole 1 GB. But how can the allocation with only 4MB contiguous pages possibly fail? And I think, in kernel space, memory is not scattered in physical memory (due to virtual memory mapping), but is linear and contiguous.

I tried to load my kernel module first with 2^10 pages allocation, but it fails and dump the stack trace:

```
[    6.037056]  [<ffffffff810041ec>] dump_trace+0x86/0x2de
[    6.037063]  [<ffffffff8122fe83>] dump_stack+0x69/0x6f
[    6.037070]  [<ffffffff8108704e>] warn_alloc_failed+0x13f/0x151
[    6.037076]  [<ffffffff8108786a>] __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x80a/0x871
[    6.037081]  [<ffffffff81087959>] __get_free_pages+0x12/0x50
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I remember correctly, `__get_free_pages` uses [buddy allocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddy_allocation), which not only *does* scatter its allocations throughout physical memory, it does so in the *worst possible* pattern for subsequent attempts to allocate large contiguous blocks. If my calculations are correct, on your system with 24GB of physical RAM, *even if* no space whatsoever were occupied by anything but buddy allocations, it would take less than 8192 order-0 (4KB) allocations to render allocation of a 4MB chunk with `__get_free_pages` impossible.

There is a thing called the [contiguous memory allocator](http://lwn.net/Articles/447405/), which is supposed to address the genuine need for large physically-contiguous allocations by device drivers; as of June 2011 it was not in the official kernel, but that was more than a year ago now.  You should look into that.

Comment: Thanks. I read the article in Wikipedia. So, if a program requests for memory order k < n (n is the maximum order allowed in the system), the memory block with size `(2^n)*PAGE_SIZE` is split until it meets memory block with `2^k` pages. One thing I don't understand, in the article, it is said that the upper limit depends on the size of memory .i.e if the total system memory is 2k, the maximum order is 8 (2^8). However, modern system must has more than that. So, obviously there must be upper limit for page order even with large memory

Comment: I only request a memory block with `2^10` (which is 1024 of contiguous 4KB pages in total). Maybe it has something to do with your comment: "even if no space whatsoever were occupied by anything but buddy allocations, it would take less than 8192 order-0 (4KB) allocations to render allocation of a 4MB chunk with __get_free_pages impossible." . I only need order 10 block with 1024 of 4KB pages. Why should I need to use 8192 order-0 blocks (which is 32MB) to allocate 4MB?

Comment: Or maybe you mean that all the physical memory blocks somehow scattered and almost no order-10 block remains in one piece, so it must allocate with lesser orders?

Comment: I mean that after some small number k (4096 < k < 8192) of order-0 allocations have happened, there will be no contiguous block that can satisfy your order-10 request.  *You* didn't do those order-0 allocations, code that ran before you got a chance did.

Comment: So, it is as I thought. The order-0 blocks scatter all over the memory and leave no room for the order-10 ("almost" is not the correct word, though). I get it, thanks.