# What are the potential problems if the option CONFIG_MIGRATION is disabled?

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, kernel

What are the potential problems if the option CONFIG_MIGRATION is disabled? I find it has some relation with the error: "page allocation failure: order:9".This error occurs frequently if this option is disabled. If it is disabled, could memory fragmentation still be reduced by other methods?

Comment: see this link for a good summation of the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11340774/5639126 The more you restrict the size of large contiguous blocks, the better chance you  have of subsequent allocations, is the way I look at it. If you are designing a router, with lots of small processes coming and going all the time, you dont need large allocations. If, on the other hand, you are running some video driver that uses large chunks of kernel memory maybe you do. You design around the use of your system.

Comment: I think in your case, a good new question to ask would be, whats the best way to reduce memory fragmentation when compaction is not possible ?

Comment: Yes, I concern about both the potential problems while these options are disabled and the methods to reduce fragmentation.

Answer (score 1):

CONFIG_MIGRATION does what it says in the kconfig help:

> Allows the migration of the physical location of pages of processes while the virtual addresses are not changed. This is useful in two situations. The first is on NUMA systems to put pages nearer to the processors accessing. The second is when allocating huge pages as migration can relocate pages to satisfy a huge page allocation instead of reclaiming.

Your error happens when the second part fails, the kernel tries to allocate pages and fails. The error is generated in mm/page_alloc.c:

```
nopage:

if (read_mems_allowed_retry(cpuset_mems_cookie))
    goto retry_cpuset;

warn_alloc(gfp_mask,
        "page allocation failure: order:%u", order);
```

That's pretty much the main problem with not having CONFIG_MIGRATION, having it makes it more likely the kernel will be able to satisfy requests for memory, especially huge pages. It's not in itself about memory fragmentation though, and the kernel will still try to reclaim or compactify memory first without migration. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. What do you mean by "It's not in itself about memory fragmentation though, and the kernel will still try to reclaim or compactify memory first without migration."? Could you please explain that in more detail for me? Thank you for the attention for this matter.

Comment: What i meant was page allocation can fail because of fragmentation or for other reasons; and migration is one way, after reclaiming old memory and compactification, to try to get a suitable memory block.  You might find these two links helpful: about fragmentation https://savvinov.com/2019/10/14/memory-fragmentation-the-silent-performance-killer/ and regarding reclaiming memory: https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand013.html

Comment: Thanks a lot. My understanding of this matter on a different level with your help. Could memory fragmentation still be reduced by other methods while both `CONFIG-MIGRATION` and `CONFIG-COMPACTION` are disabled?

Comment: @John, you can reduce memory fragmentation, there are techniques to do it, which I use myself for user applications, like creating memory pools and allocating memory from that instead of dynamically from the heap, probably the best method; you can run drivers in user space so you can control memory allocation; you can use algorithms to allocate memory that avoids fragmentation, see http://www.gii.upv.es/tlsf/ (i never used it myself though)

Comment: I see. I am very grateful to you. These are both good methods. Is there still any method that could be used by Linux kernel to reduce memory fragmentation while both `CONFIG-MIGRATION` and `CONFIG-COMPACTION` are disabled?

Comment: without compatction and migration, your options are limited:  there is merging( CONFIG_KSM) and idle page tracking ( CONFIG_IDLE_PAGE_TRACKING)

Comment: also CONFIG_FORCE_MAX_ZONE_ORDER: decrease this value will make more contiguous memory available and slow down fragmentation, but if you need more blocks of large memory, you should increase it

Comment: Thanks.Tha's good news. I still wonder why decreasing the value of CONFIG_FORCE_MAX_ZONE_ORDER would make more contiguous memory available and slow down fragmentation" other than increasing it? As per the kconfig help, which says:"This feature allows to estimate the amount of user pages that have not been touched during a given period of time. This information can be useful to tune memory cgroup limits and/or for job placement within a compute cluster". I can't see why it could reduce the fragmentation. To avoid these comments being removed to chat room, please comment just below the question.